# how to investigate Process.Start() failure?

Tags: c#, windows, service, process, process.start

hope this is a valid questions.
This is legacy code I maintain.
A Windows Services (logon as SYSTEM or A "dedicated service user") will execute a portable python exe, the python.exe run code (.pyc) with additional parameters.

**The question:**
No exception is thrown from Process.Start() and it return false, is there a way to investigate why ? Please dont paste MSDN documentation i have read it enough times.
I try to execute the python with UseShellExecute true/false, does not matter, does not work.

**The C# Windows Service code:**

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(_pythonExePath/*path to python.exe*/, exeParams/*path to pyc, and additionl params*/)
{
    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
};
var process = new Process
{
    StartInfo = processStartInfo,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};
process.Start();
```

When I executed python.exe with arguments from command line (as the "dedicated service user" and also with psexec as SYSTEM), it worked.

Call GetLastError() or Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() returned 0.
There was nothing in Event Viewer (Application, System, Security)

I have captured with process monitor the 2 executions, the one that worked, the one that did not. both executions shows python.exe started, and there are ofcourse thousands of calls afterwards.. what am i suppose to investigate ? how can i see if a security policy has blocked my exe ?

Thanks.

Comment: Process Monitor (available from the Microsoft web site) might help.

Comment: If you just need to know why something failed to start maybe you could find some clues in the windows event log

Comment: There was nothing in event viewer. No anti virus either.

Comment: Is path to the pyc relative or absolute?

Comment: @ilansch does it make a difference if the pyc is in local drive?

Answer (score 2):

Check the docs for the return value of [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start)

> true if a process resource is started; false if no new process resource is started (for example, if an existing process is reused).

So `false` does not necessarily indicate an error occurs in `Process.Start`; if there was an error, it should have thrown an exception, and it won't just set an error code and silently go to the next line.

As suggested by Harry in the comment, using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor `python.exe` is a good start.

Comment: If my process does not start, or start and stop immediatly, would i see it on procmon?

Comment: If your code fails to launch python.exe there should be an exception and that will crash the Windows service if unhandled. ProcMon just logs everything a process does even if the process live only a few milliseconds.

Comment: got the process monitor output. process was started, image was created, how come Process.Start returned false ?

Comment: @ilansch false means an existing process is reused. Microsoft Word exhibits the same behavior, when you opened a second word document when there is already one document opened, the same word application is activated , instead of launching a new word application.

Comment: i know, no existing python.exe process instance was on the VM. in addition, i saw a Create image command with python.exe on process monitor once executed.

Comment: I have no idea why false is returned. But it does means the process is started. Can you check the exit code of the process in the process monitor? Any trace of error in those thousands of calls?